# Stop request during file upload in NodeJs

Tags: file-upload, node.js

I'm write an image uploader, and I want to constrain the size of the image to under 3mb. On the server side, I can check the size of the image in the header, something like this (using express):

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (+req.headers['content-length'] > 3001000) { // About 3mb
     // Do something to stop the result
     return res.send({'error': 'some kind of error'});
  }
  // Stream in data here...
}
```

I tried to stop the req by (and permuations of)

```
req.shouldKeepAlive = false;
req.client.destroy();
res.writeHead(200, {'Connection': 'close'});
res.end()
```

None of them really "destroys" the request to prevent more data being uploaded.
req.client.destroy() seem to freeze the download, but the res.send({error... is not being sent back.

Help!

Comment: Is the file sent using a standard form upload?

Comment: yes, with enctype="multipart/form-data", accept="image/*"

Comment: Let me put it another way, can you add/modify request headers on the client side in the browser?

Comment: Pretty sure that's possible - I've got an update though, it seems like the real problem is not with node, but with NginX. It's buffering the upload before sending it to node. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_body_buffer_size  I have to investigate this further...

Comment: I think the setting you want is client_max_body_size http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size which will send a 413 "Request Entity Too Large" response back to the client. I don't think browsers understand 413 very well though, so you may want to manage the file upload using a hidden iframe or similar if this is a public-facing upload tool.

Comment: You can try to use the "Expect: 100-continue" header with the "checkContinue" event. 100-continue allows you to receive the headers first and then ask for the body if needed. http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/http.html#event_checkContinue_

Answer (score 5):

Throw an error and catch it. It will stop the file upload, allowing you to send a response.

```
try { throw new Error("Stopping file upload..."); } 
catch (e) { res.end(e.toString()); }
```

It's a bit hackish, but it works...

Comment: I do not know why your answer was not accepted. It worked for me in 2017!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
var maxSize = 30 * 1024 * 1024;    //30MB
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    var size = req.headers['content-length'];
    if (size <= maxSize) {
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            console.log("File uploading");
            if (files && files.upload) {
                res.status(200).json({fields: fields, files: files});
                fs.renameSync(files.upload[0].path, uploadDir + files.upload[0].originalFilename);
            }
            else {
              res.send("Not uploading");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        res.send(413, "File to large");
    }
```

And in case of wasting client's uploading time before get response, control it in the client javascript.

```
if (fileElement.files[0].size > maxSize) {
    ....
}
```